# Backbone.js trying to save when error callback is passed?

Tags: backbone.js

I have a collection: `conditions`. In a view, after returning an `HTTP 403` error response, I want to obviously NOT create the model:

```
var attributes = ...;
conditions.create(attributes, {
  error: function (model, response) {
    conditions.trigger('error');
    var response = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

The `error` callback is being called correctly. The response is logged correctly. But backbone still adds the (broken) model to the collection! When I look at `conditions.toJSON()`, there is a new model with some broken attributes.

I returned an error from the server, how do I insist that Backbone not add the new model to the collection?

I can do `conditions.remove(model)` in the callback, but should I have to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass `{wait: true}` to the `create` method.

> Creating a model will cause an immediate `"add"` event to be triggered on the collection, as  well as a `"sync"` event, once the model has been successfully created on the server. Pass `{wait: true}` if you'd like to wait for the server before adding the new model to the collection.

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-create

Comment: Yes. I think the best term for this (as indicated in the docs) is that Backbone is "optimistic" about model creation and syncing.